# flume: does it support collecting multiple appending files in one directory?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

The case is in my dir, I have multiple concurrently appended files, e.g:

```
error.log
info.log
error.log.1
info.log.1
...
```

The error.log and info.log are being appended in real-time. Flume has an option of TailDir, it reads file from modification time. So in this case, will it work and what will be the result like if:

```
append error.log
append info.log
append error.log
append info.log
....
```

Answer (score 0):

[Taildir](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#taildir-source) seems what you are looking for, yes. This source will detect new lines appended to existing files:

> Watch the specified files, and tail them in nearly real-time once detected new lines appended to the each files.

Regarding the order the lines will be tailed, yes, it is time-based:

> Files will be consumed in order of their modification time. File with the oldest modification time will be consumed first.

It only works with text files (no binaries), reading line by line:

> Currently this source does not support tailing binary files. It reads text files line by line.

Those lines will be put as events in the channels, and then depending on your sink or sinks, the data will be consumed in some way, stored somewhere, etc.

Comment: How does Taildir handle inode reuse problem? I mean an inode can be duplicated if the previous file is deleted and then created.